# Set the length of characters in aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch, I am getting confused over aggregation. Is it possible to set the length of the field. I mean

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/market/product/_search" -d'
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggregations": {
      "name_count": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "name",
            "size":10
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

I this can I set the length the length of the field ("field":"name").

On of the solution that I think can be, by using script.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/market/product/_search" -d'
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggregations": {
      "name_count": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "name",
            "size":10,
            "script" : "doc['name'].value.length > 2"
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

I am not sure, if I am answering myself. But I am little confused, So if anyone can answer me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want a count of records in Elasticsearch for each product name but do not want to consider product names that are shorter than three characters, you can try something like this:

```
{
    "size" : 0,
    "query" : {
        "regexp" : {
            "name" : ".{3,}"
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "name_count": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "name",
                "size":10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Specifying the regexp query will ensure that only docs with names of length > 2 are considered for your aggregation.

I based this answer on another stackoverflow post ([ElasticSearch:filtering documents based on field length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830925/elasticsearchfiltering-documents-based-on-field-length)) where another user asked how they might filter results based on field length.